# How to click first testfolder in list of items useing cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How do I click the first testfolder in list of items using cucumber:

```
<\td> test folder <\td>
<\td> test folder <\td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki) doesn't actually do any "clicking".  Per the wiki:

> Cucumber is a tool that executes plain-text functional descriptions as automated tests. The language that Cucumber understands is called Gherkin.

If you're looking to programmatically automate a browser, there are a number of webdriver-based solutions that you could use (based on your specific needs and programming language of choice).  For example, take a look at selenium, watir, or gebish.